# Shared variable between C# app and VBA app

Tags: c#, vba, memory-mapped-files

I have two apps -- a C# app and a VBA app.  I would like to create a variable in each app that points to the same memory location.  The intent is, if I change the value in one app, the other app immediately has access to that value without any additional logic to transfer that data between the apps.  In essence, I want to "remotely control" the value of the C# variable from a VBA app.

I'm not sure if this is even possible, so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I am considering a slightly different approach, now.  I may use a non-persistent Memory Mapped File to transfer the data between the two apps.  Although some code would be required to write/read the memory-mapped file, it is better than disk i/o.  I am transferring a real number between the two apps (e.g. 1.2345).  Not sure which class to use -- StreamWriter, StringWriter or TextWriter?  Any suggestions??

Thank you.

Comment: This is a very broad question. In general, you use a Cipboard object to share var values between apps. But in your case, based on the mention of "remote control" it seems more like building client-server apps, which requires much more coding. Regards,

Comment: No clipboard, or client-server intent.  All I want to do is to control the same memory space from two different apps.  Var "A" in App "A" uses same memory as Var "B" in App "B".  That's all.

Comment: Is that C# app an Office add-in? Or a stand-alone application? And where is the VBA code executed?

Comment: C# app is standalone.  Does not support unsafe code.  VBA could be executed from any office app, although I prefer Access.

Comment: You can expose a class from within your C# app as COM object, then use this COM object from within VBA to pass the value of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the variable by reference to your code in C#

While I have not tried this directly in C#, the C++ equivalent of what you're looking for is given below. Do note that this approach uses global variables and is very crude and potentially unsafe, so be very careful with dealing with memory this way. I am sure there might be more elegant ways to express this.

```
double* monitored_variable_global_pointer;

void __stdcall DoSomething(double &monitored_variable)
{
    // since monitored_variable is passed by reference, any change here, will change it on the VBA side, e.g.
    monitored_variable_global_pointer = &monitored_variable;
}
// On the VBA side, the passed variable will have to be global too for this to work.
// Also, you need the function calling convention to be stdcall for it to work with VBA, at least when making functions in C++
```

Once the code is written,

1. The C++ code is compiled into a DLL
2. The function is then called once in VBA (preferably triggered by the event that the workbook is opened, after declaration of the global variable)

You would need to do the equivalent of these steps in C# for achieving the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for this tip -- I did consider this approach, but the C# app does not support /unsafe compiler option (required for getting access to pointers in C#).  I am considering another approach, which is to use a non-persistent memory mapped file.  Thanks again.